# How to check if array values exist in another table inside my application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have the following class:-

```
public class ContactsDetails
    {
        public IEnumerable<AaaUserContactInfo> Info { get; set; }
    }
```

where AaaUserContactInfo has two foreign keys refering to other tables:-

```
public partial class AaaUserContactInfo
    {
        public long USER_ID { get; set; }
        public long CONTACTINFO_ID { get; set; }
        public string desc { get; set; }

        public virtual AaaContactInfo AaaContactInfo { get; set; }
        public virtual AaaUser AaaUser { get; set; }
    }
```

Now i have the following class which intiate a new ContactDetails object:-

```
public ActionResult CustomersDetails(long[] OrganizationIds)
{

    if (OrganizationIds == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("customer", new { isError = true });
    }
    else
    {

        var ContactsDetails = new ContactsDetails
        {
            Info = r.getcontactinfo(OrganizationIds)
        };
    }

        return View();    

}
```

now i need to return all the AaaUserContactInfo object which have their emails Ids containing part of the organization name,, something similar to:-

```
public IEnumerable<AaaUserContactInfo> getcontactinfo(long[] Organizationid)
        {
            var result = ((from uci in entities.AaaUserContactInfoes
                          join ci in entities.AaaContactInfoes on uci.CONTACTINFO_ID equals ci.CONTACTINFO_ID
                          where ci.EMAILID.ToString() == // contains any organization name in their emailIds ,, where i can get the organization name using sonthing similar to var orgname = entities.SDOrganizations.Where(a => a.ORG_ID == OrganizationIds[i]).FirstOrDefault().NAME;
                               select uci)) ;
            return result;
                                }
```

Comment: What is the `SelectRight[i]`? Do you need to find associated organizations and then to see if `EMAILID` contains at least one of the names of associated organizations?

Comment: Sorry SelectRight should be OrganizationIds, i have updated my code. what i need to to return all the objects that have their emailId containg the organization names. where i need to get all the organiation names which have their organization Ids in the passed array .. thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to use next query? I don't know what you want to do if `FirstOrDefault()` in your example return null. In my case no exception will be throws, but not records will be returned. Please note about the details of the implementation and if it worked at all.

```
public IEnumerable<AaaUserContactInfo> getcontactinfo(long[] organizationIds)
{
    var organizationNames = entities.SDOrganizations
                           .Where(org => organizationIds.Contains(org.ORG_ID))
                           .Select(org=> org.Name);


    var result = from userContactInfo in entities.AaaUserContactInfoes
                 join contactInfo in entities.AaaContactInfoes on userContactInfo.CONTACTINFO_ID equals contactInfo.CONTACTINFO_ID

                 //check if EMAILID string has at least one organizationName as substring
                 where organizationNames.Any(orgName => contactInfo.EMAILID.ToString().Contains(orgName))
                 select userContactInfo;
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT:** updated an answer to handle many organizations selected on the basis of `Organizationid`. Then `entities.AaaContactInfoes` are selected if `EMAILID` is contained in name field of at least one ogranization.

**NOTE:** i have renamed some arguments used only in the method scope, just to make code more readable.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but you are assuming that i will only have one organization name, but in my case the Organizationid[] array will have organizatin name associated with each id inside the array.

Comment: and you want `ci.EMAILID` to be equal to **at least** one of that names?

Comment: yes if the email contains part of any organization name for example @organizationname...

Comment: ok, so you mean a email string should contain at least one domain name?  I will update the answer